# Can I query the version of OpenOffice Writer from an AddIn?

Tags: java, add-in, openoffice.org

I am currently developing an OpenOffice-addin and I was wondering if I can query openoffice (writer) for its version. I would like to avoid adding more libraries if possible and rather use built-in mechanisms to do so.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ConfigurationProvider](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/configuration/ConfigurationProvider.html) service as shown in the Basic code at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=40282.

A Java example that uses the service is at:  [How do I override ODF Root RSID using the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636532/how-do-i-override-odf-root-rsid-using-the-api).

Note: IIRC, a similar question was answered on stackoverflow about a week ago.  However the question and answer seems to have been deleted.